# NULL artefacts in viewshed analysis

Tags: qgis, viewshed

I would like to have a clean viewshed analysis of an openDEM region.

I've got this elevation TIFF:
[image]

But after running the Viewshed "Visibility analysis" plugin, I obtain this result:
[image]

It's the same with the GRASS viewshed tool.

What produces these NULL pattern values on my result raster? The altitudes are consistant in my openDEM raster.

Comment: Tell us more about your elevation tif.  Where did you get it, what CRS does it use... Also did you apply any tools against it, such as reprojecting, etc?

Comment: It comes from openDEM (https://www.opendem.info/opendemeu_download_highres.html), the CRS is EPSG:3035 and I didn’t do anything to the raster.